# I want to set a password to shut down a bot on discord.py, and I don't know how to write the code. Someone help me witht the code

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to set a password to shut down a bot on discord.py, and I don't know how to write the code. Someone help me with the code

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def offline(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    msgg = await ctx.send("Please enter password in DM to continue shut down. This is a password protected command")
    msg = await ctx.author.send("Please enter password here. This command will timeout in 10 seconds")
password = []
def check(reaction, user):
    return str(password) == "testo" 

try:

    message = await client.wait_for('password', timeout=10, check=check)

except:
    await msg.edit("Password is incorrect. Please try again or contact bot developer")
    return

else:
    password.append(msg.content)

if:
    password == "testo"

    await msgg.edit("Bot is shutting down")
    await ctx.author.send("Password is correct. Bot will be shutting down")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    await msgg.edit(content="Bot has shut down. To start it again, please contact bot dev")
    await bot.logout()
    return
```

Thats all I got so far

Comment: Any errors? Maybe share the traceback you get in your console after running the code.

Comment: There is too much errors, the code is just not correct since I almost have no idea of what I am doing. I somewhat do and that's what I wrote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some formatting errors in your code, even if the approach was not bad.

You need to include a real/existing `check` function first. This will check that the reply was really made in the bot's direct message and that it came from the user who executed the command.

We then wait with a `wait_for` for an answer. You can set `timeout` as you like or omit it. Then we check the `content` of the message and if it matches the set password then the bot shuts down, otherwise it does not. *(This will take some time!)*

**Your full code would be:**

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def offline(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.message.author.mention}, check your DM's!")
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.author.send("Please enter the password to shut me down!")

    def check(m):
        return ctx.author == m.author and isinstance(m.channel, discord.DMChannel) # Check that it is a DM channel
    try:
        test = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=100) # We wait 100 seconds for a user response/message in the DMs
        if test.content == "123": # Content can be changed to whatever you want
            await ctx.author.send("Correct password, I will shutdown.")
            await client.logout()
        else:
            await ctx.author.send("Wrong password, run the command again!")
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.author.send("The time was not enough? Alright.", delete_after=5)
```

Comment: Sure, glad I was able to help. Do not forget to "accept" the most helpful answer to help other people find the best solution if they face the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define your command named `offline` like this:

```
password = '12345'

@client.command()
async def offline(ctx, *, password_check=None):
    if password_check and password_check == password:
        await ctx.message.channel.purge(limit=1)
        await ctx.send('Shutting down bot...')
        await ctx.bot.logout()
    elif not password_check:
        await ctx.send('Please enter the password!')
    else:
        await ctx.send('You got the password wrong.')
```